# exp_stash rows aren't being expired / deleted

Tags: stash

I'm using stash fairly heavily in an addon and creating user scoped stash variables. All worked great but I'm finding that my exp_stash db table is growing and growing without any rows ever expiring.

Is there a setting I'm missing somewhere or is buying Mustash the only way to prune the exp_stash table (other than writing an addon myself and triggering it with cron).

Cheers

Jim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mustash](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/Mustash) is not the only way but it is the most flexible and granular way I can think of. If you are using Stash for caching, Mustash will be your best solution in terms of establishing cache clearing rules.

That being said [other, possibly more "brutal"](https://github.com/domstubbs/ee-stash-breaker), solutions exist that might fit your needs too. These make good use of the [Stash Unset/Destro methods](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/Using-stash-methods-in-your-own-add-ons#unset--destroy).